# Generate functions using Macros in C

Tags: c, function, macros

I have the following macro:

```
‎#define GTR(type) \‎
type type##_gtr(type a, type b) \‎
‎{ \‎
‎   return a > b ? a : b;\‎
‎}‎
```

I understand that it generates functions, but if `GTR(unsigned int)` expands outside `main()`, how do I call the generated function? `_gtr(a, b)` does not work...

Comment: By the way, `void main()` is not allowed by standard C. You should use `int main()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GTR(unsigned)` would expand to:

```
unsigned unsigned_gtr(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
‎   return a > b ? a : b;
}‎
```

In that case, you should call `unsigned_gtr(a, b)`.

`GTR(unsigned int)`, however, would fail with a syntax error because you are having two separate tokens and the name of the function cannot be properly produced.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to write `unsigned int_gtr(a,b)` so it would not work for that type with the macro definition you have created.

The reason is that the preprocessor simply replaces the `type` parameter and joins it to the text after the ##.

You could do something like create a typedef for unisgned int so there were no spaces and then use that, e.g.:

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
GTR(uint)
...
uint_gtr(a,b)
```

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
type##_gtr
```

inside the macro is glueing together the value of the `type` argument with the text `_gtr`. This happens between the return type and the opening parenthesis of the argument list, i.e. this forms the name of the function.

So if you use `GTR(unsigned int)`, you fail since the full function prototype ends up looking like this:

```
unsigned int unsigned int_gtr(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
```

which is not syntactically correct. Basically, the macro has a weakness in that it assumes type names cannot contain spaces, which is not true in C.

If you use `GTR(unsigned)`, though, you should call it as `unsigned_gtr()`.